# Add a new rule to .htaccess whitout overwrite https server rule

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem when I try to add a new rule to my .htaccess. On my server I activated a rule which redirects http to https and it works fine but when I add a new rule to my .htaccess then https disappears.

My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
ErrorDocument 403 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/

</IfModule>
```

I need to redirect every request to index.php (mvc) and it should work together with https.

I tried deactivating the redirection from the server and to write everything into my .htaccess like this:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
ErrorDocument 403 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
```

But I get the error `The page isn't redirecting properly`. How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: This looks strange... There is no immediate redirection to https at all here. Only error documents are redirected. So you rely on first having to generate an error to send clients to https? What kind of logic is _that_ ?

Comment: I activated a function on my private control panel which redirects automatically http to https, so I don't have to write any rule to force https in .htaccess.

Comment: what is private control panel?

Comment: Also, first Rewrite should be succeded by `[AND]` .. Like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [AND]`

Comment: The control panel furnished by my internet service provider. It's a simple control panel in which I can activate the https and redirect http to https. That's all. No more actions are permitted. I can deactivate the redirection but then I have to manually add it on my .htaccess. I can do it if somebody help me to make these two rules live together.

Comment: @hacker315 The logical `[AND]` is the default, it is perfectly fine to omit it.

Comment: What ever that logic is your provider offers (how should _we_ know, you'd have to tell us...), it apparently is in conflict with your distributed control file, isn't it? So I'd say it is worth a try to have everything in one place. Does that work? Not _that_ hard to give it a try...

Comment: If I try to force the https on my .htaccess I get an error: ```The page isn't redirecting properly```.

Comment: _Show us_ what you tried then, how else are we supposed to be able to tell where you might have done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved it with the help of my internet provider. This is the final code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# redirect to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
ErrorDocument 403 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
```